# Librería NET-SNMP para nodejs, distintos OIDS me dan el mismo resultado

Tags: nodejs, sailsjs

Distintos OIDS me dan el mismo resultado, pero si los solicito uno por sesión si retornan su valor correcto, a qué se debe o como puedo solucionar este problema.

```
var options = {
              port: 9002,
              retries: 1,
              timeout: 100000,
              version: snmp.Version1,
              idBitsSize: 16
            };

          var session = snmp.createSession ("192.168.0.56", "public",options);

oids = ["1.3.6.1.4.1.28018.1.10.6.0","1.3.6.1.4.1.28018.1.10.12.0"];

              session.get (oids, function (error, varbinds) {
                if (error) {
                  console.error (error);
                } else {
                  for (var i = 0; i < varbinds.length; i++)
                    if (snmp.isVarbindError (varbinds[i])){
                      console.error (snmp.varbindError (varbinds[i]));
                    }
                    else{
                      console.log (varbinds[i].oid + " = " + varbinds[i].value);
                    }

                }
              });

              session.trap (snmp.TrapType.LinkDown, function (error) {
                if (error)
                  console.error (error);
              });
```

El resultado que obtengo por consola es el siguiente:

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.28018.1.10.12.0 = 65
1.3.6.1.4.1.28018.1.10.6.0 = 65
```

El primero OID me debería dar la temperatura de la batería y el segundo el nivel de carga de la batería, pero ambos me dan el nivel de carga. Si realizo la petición por cada OID, el resultado si es el valor correcto.

¿A qué se debe o cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar, será bueno especificar la clase de dispositivo al que estás accediendo mediante el protocolo SNMP.

Debes tener en cuenta que posiblemente algunos de los oids a los que intentas acceder son de tipo privado y/o no pertenecen a ese dispositivo, es por eso que talvez tengas tu error.

Puedes encontrar una referencia a tus oids en este sitio: [OID Repository](http://www.oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?nb=28018&f=1.3.6.1.4.1&a=display)

---

Puedes leer un poco más sobre SNMP [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_simple_de_administraci%C3%B3n_de_red) y sobre OIDS [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_de_objeto)

Comment: El dispositivo es un celular con android, al solicitar cada OID independientemente si retornar los valores correctos, pero al colocarlos como array ocurre el problema.

Comment: Lo siento amigo, pero segùn parece la forma en que estás usando la librería es correcta según la documentación